# Tableau line graph is separated into two panels and I want to combine these

Tags: tableau-desktop

Preface: I ALREADY KNOW ABOUT THE DUAL AXIS FEATURE. Unfortunately, this is not the solution I need.

I have a line graph of sales over the past year. The x-axis of my graph is delineated by months. However, since I want the months to appear in order (August 2020 to August 2021) I am forced to delineate by year in addition to months. This would be find, except there is a giant discontinuity in my graph between the year 2020 and the year 2021 in Dec/Jan. It looks as though my graph is separated into two separate panels based on year. Does anyone know how to combine these panels and eliminate the discontinuity?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

First only have one Date field on the columns shelf.

Then right click on that pill and select the **second** Month choice. You should get a green pill and one horizontal axis and a mark per Month/Year. That choice invokes the DateTrunc() function on your Date field (you can see by double clicking on the pill) and is displayed as continuous (green) by default.

People often say this choices causes the date to be treated as continuous - but that is only a side-effect, and can be changed. The more fundamental effect is that it calls DateTrunc() instead of DatePart() on your date field.